# Trying to use the method "Stiff" (Rosenbrock method implementation) from the book "Numerical Recipes in C".

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The program is compilable but I don't think it works correctly. According to the book, we need also method "odeint" for adaptive stepsize adjustment and fully implement Rosenbrock method. I used the "odeint" method given in the book and changed the call to "rkqs" with a call to "Stiff".

(*stiff)(y, xStart, N, &x, h, eps, yscal, &hdid, &hnext, derivs);

I think the problem is in yscal vector. The recommendation in the book was this: yscal = max(C, |y|). With sycal the error is to be scaled (C must be of order unity).

So in odeint I'm fillign this vector with values: 
yscal[i] = FMAX(1, fabs(y[i]));

I'm testing it using the given example in the book:

(y1)' = −.013y1 − 1000y1y3

(y2)' = −2500y2y3

(y3)' = −.013y1 − 1000y1y3 − 2500y2y3

with initial conditions

y1(0) = 1, y2(0) = 1, y3(0) = 0

But the problem is that fabs(y[i]) is always less than 1, it is even less than 0.0001. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I know that it's a longshot, but if you have any idea what I'm doing wrong, please tell.

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. I tried registering on NR forum but couldn't succeed, they're not sending the mail verification for some reason.

Ok, here is the full source file code and the header file:

**Source code:**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "nrutil.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SAFETY 0.9
#define GROW 1.5
#define PGROW -0.25
#define SHRNK 0.5
#define PSHRNK (-1.0/3.0)
#define ERRCON 0.1296
#define MAXTRY 40
//Here NMAX is the maximum value of n; GROW and SHRNK are the largest and smallest factors
//by which stepsize can change in one step; ERRCON equals (GROW/SAFETY) raised to the power
//(1/PGROW) and handles the case when errmax  0.
#define GAM (1.0/2.0)
#define A21 2.0
#define A31 (48.0/25.0)
#define A32 (6.0/25.0)
#define C21 -8.0
#define C31 (372.0/25.0)
#define C32 (12.0/5.0)
#define C41 (-112.0/125.0)
#define C42 (-54.0/125.0)
#define C43 (-2.0/5.0)
#define B1 (19.0/9.0)
#define B2 (1.0/2.0)
#define B3 (25.0/108.0)
#define B4 (125.0/108.0)
#define E1 (17.0/54.0)
#define E2 (7.0/36.0)
#define E3 0.0
#define E4 (125.0/108.0)
#define C1X (1.0/2.0)
#define C2X (-3.0/2.0)
#define C3X (121.0/50.0)
#define C4X (29.0/250.0)
#define A2X 1.0
#define A3X (3.0/5.0)
#define NRANSI
#define TINY 1.0e-20;
#define NR_END 1
#define FREE_ARG char*
#define FMAX(a, b) (maxarg1 = a, maxarg2 = b, (maxarg1) > (maxarg2) ? (maxarg1) : (maxarg2))
#define FMIN(a, b) (maxarg1 = a, maxarg2 = b, (maxarg1) < (maxarg2) ? (maxarg1) : (maxarg2))
#define MAXSTP 10000
#define N 3

/// <summary>
/// Fourth-order Rosenbrock step for integrating stiff o.d.e.’s, with monitoring of local truncation
/// error to adjust stepsize. Input are the dependent variable vector y[1..n] and its derivative
/// dydx[1..n] at the starting value of the independent variable x. Also input are the stepsize to
/// be attempted htry, the required accuracy eps, and the vector yscal[1..n] against which
/// the error is scaled. On output, y and x are replaced by their new values, hdid is the stepsize
/// that was actually accomplished, and hnext is the estimated next stepsize. derivs is a usersupplied
/// routine that computes the derivatives of the right-hand side with respect to x, while
/// jacobn (a fixed name) is a user-supplied routine that computes the Jacobi matrix of derivatives
/// of the right-hand side with respect to the components of y.
/// </summary>
///<param name="y">Initial y values</param>
///<param name="dydx">Initial y derivative values</param>
///<param name="n">Dimension of y</param>
///<param name="x">Value of x</param>
///<param name="htry">The stepsize to be attempted</param>
///<param name="eps">The required accuracy</param>
///<param name="yscal">The vector [1..n] against which the error is scaled</param>
///<param name="hdid">The stepsize that was actually accomplished</param>
///<param name="hnext">The estimated next stepsize</param>
///<param name="derivs">Pass the name of the function derivs</param>
void stiff(float y[], float dydx[], int n, float *x, float htry, float eps,
           float yscal[], float *hdid, float *hnext,
           void (*derivs)(float, float [], float []))
{
    void jacobn(float x, float y[], float dfdx[], float **dfdy, int n);
    void lubksb(float **a, int n, int *indx, float b[]);
    void ludcmp(float **a, int n, int *indx, float *d);
    int i,j,jtry,*indx;
    int counter = 0; //GJA.New
    float d,errmax,h,xsav,**a,*dfdx,**dfdy,*dysav,*err;
    float *g1,*g2,*g3,*g4,*ysav;
    indx=ivector(1,n);
    a=matrix(1,n,1,n);
    dfdx=vector(1,n);
    dfdy=matrix(1,n,1,n);
    dysav=vector(1,n);
    err=vector(1,n);
    g1=vector(1,n);
    g2=vector(1,n);
    g3=vector(1,n);
    g4=vector(1,n);
    ysav=vector(1,n);
    xsav=(*x);

    //Save initial values.
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        ysav[i]=y[i];
        dysav[i]=dydx[i];
    }


    jacobn(xsav,ysav,dfdx,dfdy,n);
    //The user must supply this routine to return the n-by-n matrix dfdy and the vector dfdx.

    h=htry; //Set stepsize to the initial trial value.

    for (jtry=1;jtry<=MAXTRY;jtry++) 
    {
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        { //Set up the matrix 1 − γhf'
            for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
                a[i][j] = -dfdy[i][j];
            a[i][i] += 1.0/(GAM*h);
        }

        ludcmp(a,n,indx,&d); //LU decomposition of the matrix.

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            //Set up right-hand side for g1.
            g1[i]=dysav[i]+h*C1X*dfdx[i];

        lubksb(a,n,indx,g1); //Solve for g1.

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            //Compute intermediate values of y and x.
            y[i]=ysav[i]+A21*g1[i]; 

        *x=xsav+A2X*h;

        (*derivs)(*x,y,dydx); //Compute dydx at the intermediate values.

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            //Set up right-hand side for g2.
            g2[i]=dydx[i]+h*C2X*dfdx[i]+C21*g1[i]/h;

        lubksb(a,n,indx,g2); //Solve for g2.

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            //Compute intermediate values of y and x.
            y[i]=ysav[i]+A31*g1[i]+A32*g2[i];

        *x=xsav+A3X*h;
        (*derivs)(*x,y,dydx); //Compute dydx at the intermediate values.

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            //Set up right-hand side for g3.
            g3[i]=dydx[i]+h*C3X*dfdx[i]+(C31*g1[i]+C32*g2[i])/h;

        lubksb(a,n,indx,g3); //Solve for g3.

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            //Set up right-hand side for g4.
            g4[i]=dydx[i]+h*C4X*dfdx[i]+(C41*g1[i]+C42*g2[i]+C43*g3[i])/h;

        lubksb(a,n,indx,g4); //Solve for g4.

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        { //Get fourth-order estimate of y and error estimate.
            y[i]=ysav[i]+B1*g1[i]+B2*g2[i]+B3*g3[i]+B4*g4[i];
            err[i]=E1*g1[i]+E2*g2[i]+E3*g3[i]+E4*g4[i];
            printf("y = %f \n", fabs(y[i]));
        }

        *x=xsav+h;

        if (*x == xsav) 
            nrerror("stepsize not significant in stiff");   
        errmax=0.0; //Evaluate accuracy.

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            errmax=FMAX(errmax,fabs(err[i]/yscal[i]));
            errmax /= eps; //Scale relative to required tolerance.

        if (errmax <= 1.0) { //Step succeeded. Compute size of next step and re-
            *hdid=h; //turn.
            //*hnext=(errmax > ERRCON ? SAFETY*h*pow(errmax,PGROW) : GROW*h); //GJA.Old
            *hnext=(errmax > ERRCON ? SAFETY*h*pow((double)errmax,PGROW) : GROW*h); //GJA.New
            free_vector(ysav,1,n);
            free_vector(g4,1,n);
            free_vector(g3,1,n);
            free_vector(g2,1,n);
            free_vector(g1,1,n);
            free_vector(err,1,n);
            free_vector(dysav,1,n);
            free_matrix(dfdy,1,n,1,n);
            free_vector(dfdx,1,n);
            free_matrix(a,1,n,1,n);
            free_ivector(indx,1,n);

            printf("success \n"); //GJA.New

            return;
        } 
        else 
        {   //Truncation error too large, reduce stepsize.
            //*hnext=SAFETY*h*pow(errmax,PSHRNK); //GJA.Old
            *hnext=SAFETY*h*pow((double)errmax,PSHRNK); //GJA.New
            h=(h >= 0.0 ? FMAX(*hnext,SHRNK*h) : FMIN(*hnext,SHRNK*h));
            counter++; //GJA.New
            printf("Counter = %d \n", counter); //GJA.New
            printf("Stepsize = %f \n", h); //GJA.New
        }

    } //Go back and re-try step.

    nrerror("exceeded MAXTRY in stiff");
}

void ludcmp(float **a, int n, int *indx, float *d)
{
        int i,imax,j,k;
        float big,dum,sum,temp;
        float *vv;

        vv=vector(1,n);
        *d=1.0;
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
                big=0.0;
                for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
                        if ((temp=fabs(a[i][j])) > big) big=temp;
                if (big == 0.0) nrerror("Singular matrix in routine ludcmp");
                vv[i]=1.0/big;
        }

        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
                for (i=1;i<j;i++)
                {
                        sum=a[i][j];
                        for (k=1;k<i;k++)
                            sum -= a[i][k]*a[k][j];
                        a[i][j]=sum;
                }

                big=0.0;
                for (i=j;i<=n;i++) {
                        sum=a[i][j];
                        for (k=1;k<j;k++)
                                sum -= a[i][k]*a[k][j];
                        a[i][j]=sum;
                        if ( (dum=vv[i]*fabs(sum)) >= big) {
                                big=dum;
                                imax=i;
                        }
                }
                if (j != imax) 
                {
                        for (k=1;k<=n;k++)
                        {
                                dum=a[imax][k];
                                a[imax][k]=a[j][k];
                                a[j][k]=dum;
                        }
                        *d = -(*d);
                        vv[imax]=vv[j];
                }

                indx[j]=imax;
                if (a[j][j] == 0.0) a[j][j]=TINY;
                if (j != n) {
                        dum=1.0/(a[j][j]);
                        for (i=j+1;i<=n;i++) a[i][j] *= dum;
                }
        }
        free_vector(vv,1,n);
}

void lubksb(float **a, int n, int *indx, float b[])
{
        int i,ii=0,ip,j;
        float sum;

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
                ip=indx[i];
                sum=b[ip];
                b[ip]=b[i];
                if (ii)
                        for (j=ii;j<=i-1;j++) sum -= a[i][j]*b[j];
                else if (sum) ii=i;
                b[i]=sum;
        }
        for (i=n;i>=1;i--)
        {
                sum=b[i];
                for (j=i+1;j<=n;j++) sum -= a[i][j]*b[j];
                b[i]=sum/a[i][i];
        }
}

void nrerror(char error_text[])
/* Numerical Recipes standard error handler */
{
        fprintf(stderr,"Numerical Recipes run-time error...\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",error_text);
        fprintf(stderr,"...now exiting to system...\n");
        exit(1);
}

void free_ivector(int *v, long nl, long nh)
/* free an int vector allocated with ivector() */
{
        free((FREE_ARG) (v+nl-NR_END));
}

void free_matrix(float **m, long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch)
/* free a float matrix allocated by matrix() */
{
        free((FREE_ARG) (m[nrl]+ncl-NR_END));
        free((FREE_ARG) (m+nrl-NR_END));
}

void free_vector(float *v, long nl, long nh)
/* free a float vector allocated with vector() */
{
        free((FREE_ARG) (v+nl-NR_END));
}

int *ivector(long nl, long nh)
/* allocate an int vector with subscript range v[nl..nh] */
{
        int *v;

        v=(int *)malloc((size_t) ((nh-nl+1+NR_END)*sizeof(int)));
        if (!v) nrerror("allocation failure in ivector()");
        return v-nl+NR_END;
}

float **matrix(long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch)
/* allocate a float matrix with subscript range m[nrl..nrh][ncl..nch] */
{
        long i, nrow=nrh-nrl+1,ncol=nch-ncl+1;
        float **m;

        /* allocate pointers to rows */
        m=(float **) malloc((size_t)((nrow+NR_END)*sizeof(float*)));
        if (!m) nrerror("allocation failure 1 in matrix()");
        m += NR_END;
        m -= nrl;

        /* allocate rows and set pointers to them */
        m[nrl]=(float *) malloc((size_t)((nrow*ncol+NR_END)*sizeof(float)));
        if (!m[nrl]) nrerror("allocation failure 2 in matrix()");
        m[nrl] += NR_END;
        m[nrl] -= ncl;

        for(i=nrl+1;i<=nrh;i++) m[i]=m[i-1]+ncol;

        /* return pointer to array of pointers to rows */
        return m;
}

float *vector(long nl, long nh)
/* allocate a float vector with subscript range v[nl..nh] */
{
        float *v;

        v=(float *)malloc((size_t) ((nh-nl+1+NR_END)*sizeof(float)));
        if (!v) nrerror("allocation failure in vector()");
        return v-nl+NR_END;
}

/*
Example from NR
*/
void derivs(float x, float y[], float dydx[])
{
    dydx[1] = -0.013*y[1]-1000.0*y[1]*y[3];
    dydx[2] = -2500.0*y[2]*y[3];
    dydx[3] = -0.013*y[1]-1000.0*y[1]*y[3]-2500.0*y[2]*y[3];
}

/*
Example from NR
*/
void jacobn(float x, float y[], float dfdx[], float **dfdy, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) dfdx[i]=0.0;
    dfdy[1][1] = -0.013-1000.0*y[3];
    dfdy[1][2]=0.0;
    dfdy[1][3] = -1000.0*y[1];
    dfdy[2][1]=0.0;
    dfdy[2][2] = -2500.0*y[3];
    dfdy[2][3] = -2500.0*y[2];
    dfdy[3][1] = -0.013-1000.0*y[3];
    dfdy[3][2] = -2500.0*y[3];
    dfdy[3][3] = -1000.0*y[1]-2500.0*y[2];
}
/*
Robertson chemical kinetics problem
*/
void derivsRob(float x, float y[], float dydx[])
{
    dydx[1] = -0.04*y[1] + 10000.0*y[2]*y[3];
    dydx[2] = 0.04*y[1] - 10000.0*y[2]*y[3] - 30000000.0*y[2]*y[2];
    dydx[3] = 30000000.0*y[2]*y[2];
}

/*
Robertson chemical kinetics problem
*/
void jacobnRob(float x, float y[], float dfdx[], float **dfdy, int n)
{

    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) dfdx[i]=0.0;
    dfdy[1][1] = -0.04;
    dfdy[1][2] = 0.04;
    dfdy[1][3] = 0.0;
    dfdy[2][1] = 10000.0*y[3];
    dfdy[2][2] = -10000.0*y[3]-30000000.0;
    dfdy[2][3] = 30000000.0;
    dfdy[3][1] = 10000.0*y[2];
    dfdy[3][2] = -10000.0*y[2];
    dfdy[3][3] = 0.0;
}

//extern int kmax,kount; //GJA.Old
//extern float *xp,**yp,dxsav; //GJA.Old
int kmax,kount; //GJA.New
float *xp,**yp,dxsav; //GJA.New

void odeint(float ystart[], int nvar, float x1, float x2, float eps, float h1,
            float hmin, int *nok, int *nbad,
            void (*derivs)(float, float [], float []),
            //void (*rkqs)(float [], float [], int, float *, float, float, float [], //GJA.Old
            //float *, float *, void (*)(float, float [], float [])))   //GJA.Old
            void(*stiff)(float y[], float dydx[], int n, float *x, float htry, float eps, //GJA.New
            float yscal[], float *hdid, float *hnext, //GJA.New
            void (*derivs)(float, float [], float []))) //GJA.New

{
    int nstp,i;
    float xsav,x,hnext,hdid,h;
    float *yscal,*y,*dydx;
    float xStart[] = {0, 1, 1, 0}; //Example from NR
    //float xStart[] = {0, 1, 0, 0}; //Robertson chemical kinetics problem
    int counter = 0;

    yscal=vector(1,nvar);

    y=vector(1,nvar);

    dydx=vector(1,nvar);

    x=x1;

    h=SIGN(h1,x2-x1);

    *nok = (*nbad) = kount = 0;

    for (i=1;i<=nvar;i++) 
        y[i]=ystart[i];

    if (kmax > 0) 
        xsav=x-dxsav*2.0;

    for (nstp=1;nstp<=MAXSTP;nstp++) 
    {
        (*derivs)(x,y,dydx);

        for (i=1;i<=nvar;i++)
        {
            //yscal[i]=fabs(y[i])+fabs(dydx[i]*h)+TINY; //GJA.Old
            yscal[i] = FMAX(1, fabs(y[i])); //GJA.New
        }

        if (kmax > 0 && kount < kmax-1 && fabs(x-xsav) > fabs(dxsav))
        {
            xp[++kount]=x;
            for (i=1;i<=nvar;i++) yp[i][kount]=y[i];
            xsav=x;
        }

        if ((x+h-x2)*(x+h-x1) > 0.0) //(x+h) is outside interval (x1; x2)
            h=x2-x;

        //(*rkqs)(y,dydx,nvar,&x,h,eps,yscal,&hdid,&hnext,derivs); //GJA.Old
        (*stiff)(y, xStart, N, &x, h, eps, yscal, &hdid, &hnext, derivs); //GJA.New
        counter++;
        printf("Stiff was called from Odeint %d \n", counter); //GJA.New
        if (hdid == h) 
            ++(*nok); 
        else 
            ++(*nbad);

        if ((x-x2)*(x2-x1) >= 0.0) 
        {
            for (i=1;i<=nvar;i++) ystart[i]=y[i];

            if (kmax) 
            {
                xp[++kount]=x;
                for (i=1;i<=nvar;i++) 
                    yp[i][kount]=y[i];              
            }

            free_vector(dydx,1,nvar);
            free_vector(y,1,nvar);
            free_vector(yscal,1,nvar);

            return;
        }

        if (fabs(hnext) <= hmin) nrerror("Step size too small in odeint");
        h=hnext;
    }

    nrerror("Too many steps in routine odeint");
}


 /*
    Fourth-order Rosenbrock step for integrating stiff o.d.e.’s, with monitoring of local truncation
    error to adjust stepsize. Input are the dependent variable vector y[1..n] and its derivative
    dydx[1..n] at the starting value of the independent variable x. Also input are the stepsize to
    be attempted htry, the required accuracy eps, and the vector yscal[1..n] against which
    the error is scaled. On output, y and x are replaced by their new values, hdid is the stepsize
    that was actually accomplished, and hnext is the estimated next stepsize. derivs is a usersupplied
    routine that computes the derivatives of the right-hand side with respect to x, while
    jacobn (a fixed name) is a user-supplied routine that computes the Jacobi matrix of derivatives
    of the right-hand side with respect to the components of y.
 */
 int main()
 {
    float x = 50; //TODO What does "Integrated up to x = 50" mean? Is x number of points or just a value?
    float eps = 0.0001; 
    float yStart[]  = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    float dydx[] = {0, 1, 1, 0};
    float yScal[]       = {0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001};
    float htry          = 0.00029;
    float h1 = 0.1;
    float hmin = 0.0;
    float x1 = 0;
    float x2 = 50;
    float hnext = 1; //TODO should I initilize this variable?
    float hdid = 1; // TODO should I initilize this variable?

    int nok;
    int nbad;
    int i;

    xp=vector(1,200);
    yp=matrix(1,10,1,200);
    kmax = 10000;

    dxsav=(x2-x1)/20.0;

    printf("Before: \n");
    printf("x = %f \n" , x);
    printf("eps = %f \n" , eps);
    printf("htry = %f \n" , htry);
    printf("hnext = %f \n" , hnext);
    printf("hdid = %f \n" , hdid);
    printf("y = %f \n" , yStart);
    printf("\n");

    //stiff(yStart, dydx, 3, &x, htry, eps, yScal, &hdid, &hnext, derivs);
    odeint(yStart, N, x1, x2, eps, htry, hmin, &nok, &nbad, derivs, stiff);

    printf("After: \n");
    printf("x = %f \n" , x);
    printf("eps = %f \n" , eps);
    printf("htry = %f \n" , htry);
    printf("hnext = %f \n" , hnext);
    printf("hdid = %f \n" , hdid);
    printf("y = %f \n" , yStart);

    printf("\nSuccessful steps: %3d\n",nok);
    printf("Bad steps: %3d\n",nbad);
    printf("\nStored intermediate values: %3d\n",kount);

    for(i=1;i<=kount;i++)
        printf("%10.4f %16.6f\n", xp[i],yp[1][i]);

    system("pause");    
 }
```

**header file nrutil.h:**

```
//#ifndef _NR_UTILS_H_ //GJA.Old
#define _NR_UTILS_H_

static float sqrarg;
#define SQR(a) ((sqrarg=(a)) == 0.0 ? 0.0 : sqrarg*sqrarg)

static double dsqrarg;
#define DSQR(a) ((dsqrarg=(a)) == 0.0 ? 0.0 : dsqrarg*dsqrarg)

static double dmaxarg1,dmaxarg2;
#define DMAX(a,b) (dmaxarg1=(a),dmaxarg2=(b),(dmaxarg1) > (dmaxarg2) ?\
        (dmaxarg1) : (dmaxarg2))

static double dminarg1,dminarg2;
#define DMIN(a,b) (dminarg1=(a),dminarg2=(b),(dminarg1) < (dminarg2) ?\
        (dminarg1) : (dminarg2))

static float maxarg1,maxarg2;
#define FMAX(a,b) (maxarg1=(a),maxarg2=(b),(maxarg1) > (maxarg2) ?\
        (maxarg1) : (maxarg2))

static float minarg1,minarg2;
#define FMIN(a,b) (minarg1=(a),minarg2=(b),(minarg1) < (minarg2) ?\
        (minarg1) : (minarg2))

static long lmaxarg1,lmaxarg2;
#define LMAX(a,b) (lmaxarg1=(a),lmaxarg2=(b),(lmaxarg1) > (lmaxarg2) ?\
        (lmaxarg1) : (lmaxarg2))

static long lminarg1,lminarg2;
#define LMIN(a,b) (lminarg1=(a),lminarg2=(b),(lminarg1) < (lminarg2) ?\
        (lminarg1) : (lminarg2))

static int imaxarg1,imaxarg2;
#define IMAX(a,b) (imaxarg1=(a),imaxarg2=(b),(imaxarg1) > (imaxarg2) ?\
        (imaxarg1) : (imaxarg2))

static int iminarg1,iminarg2;
#define IMIN(a,b) (iminarg1=(a),iminarg2=(b),(iminarg1) < (iminarg2) ?\
        (iminarg1) : (iminarg2))

#define SIGN(a,b) ((b) >= 0.0 ? fabs(a) : -fabs(a))

//#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(ANSI) || defined(NRANSI) /* ANSI */

void nrerror(char error_text[]);
float *vector(long nl, long nh);
int *ivector(long nl, long nh);
unsigned char *cvector(long nl, long nh);
unsigned long *lvector(long nl, long nh);
double *dvector(long nl, long nh);
float **matrix(long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
double **dmatrix(long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
int **imatrix(long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
float **submatrix(float **a, long oldrl, long oldrh, long oldcl, long oldch,
    long newrl, long newcl);
float **convert_matrix(float *a, long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
float ***f3tensor(long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch, long ndl, long ndh);
void free_vector(float *v, long nl, long nh);
void free_ivector(int *v, long nl, long nh);
void free_cvector(unsigned char *v, long nl, long nh);
void free_lvector(unsigned long *v, long nl, long nh);
void free_dvector(double *v, long nl, long nh);
void free_matrix(float **m, long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
void free_dmatrix(double **m, long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
void free_imatrix(int **m, long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
void free_submatrix(float **b, long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
void free_convert_matrix(float **b, long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch);
void free_f3tensor(float ***t, long nrl, long nrh, long ncl, long nch,
    long ndl, long ndh);

//#else /* ANSI */
/* traditional - K&R */

void nrerror();
float *vector();
float **matrix();
float **submatrix();
float **convert_matrix();
float ***f3tensor();
double *dvector();
double **dmatrix();
int *ivector();
int **imatrix();
unsigned char *cvector();
unsigned long *lvector();
void free_vector();
void free_dvector();
void free_ivector();
void free_cvector();
void free_lvector();
void free_matrix();
void free_submatrix();
void free_convert_matrix();
void free_dmatrix();
void free_imatrix();
void free_f3tensor();
```

Comment: Do you expect the values of y[i] to always be less than 1? or is the problem that the values you have are less than 1?  You might post this on stackoverflow with much more of the source code.  I can think of lots of potential issues in the code but without actually seeing the source it is hard to identify a bug.

Comment: TravisJ, thanks for the answer. I would say that I don't expect the values of y[i] to always be less than 1, but I'm not completely sure. You can see the full source code and the header file, please have a look.

Comment: I'm not certain I can help... this is much more complicated than I was expecting.  I would post up on stackoverflow... and try to reduce your code down to a "minimal" example that still shows the problem.  I'm not sure what the (*stiff) part is doing in the odeint list of parameters... but you use a float y[] there and then declare a vector y in the body of odeint.  I don't know if there's a name recycling issue or not... I'm afraid I'm not much help.

Comment: "main" calls "odeint", "odeint" calls "stiff". My guess is that I made a mistake in one of these lines: 

1. In "odeint" there is this line, where I'm setting the values of yscal vector coordinates.: 
yscal[i] = FMAX(1, fabs(y[i])); //GJA.New. 

2. This line in "odeint" where I commented the call to "rkqs" and added a call to "stiff", it is possible that I passed the parameters incorrectly:
(*stiff)(y, xStart, N, &x, h, eps, yscal, &hdid, &hnext, derivs); //GJA.New

Many users on NR forum have succeeded to use this method, I'd love to be able to contact them somehow...

Comment: that code looks hideous. now I recall why every time I skim through "Numerical Recipes in C” I end up closing it and promising myself I won't open it again.

Comment: Yes, I think I know that feeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found C++ code which works correctly: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/stiff_systems.html

It uses odeint library (you can download it from here: http://www.boost.org/)